# Why is there a Commander Keen sprite in Doom II?

Tags: doom-2, commander-keen

In the original sprites in Doom II, there is a sprite of Commander Keen. Why is he there?

[image]

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_keen#Keen_in_other_games). It's like Terraria referencing Zelda with the Green Tunic (aka. The Hero Outfit), or Duke Nukem Forever referencing Halo (*I don't need no Power Suit*) and much, much more. Why did they do that? They probably played and enjoyed those games and decided to honour those.

Comment: @Nolonar well in ID's case (as I note in my answer) it's because they *made* Keen, he's also in one of two levels that are Wolfenstein references

Comment: although not the case here, leaving unused textures in atlases for first person shooters is a very common thing to do with big titles; perhaps just not to risk breaking anything, or in hope for level expansion packs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's actually in the game, it's not an unused sprite. It's in [level 32: Grosse](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Level_32:_Grosse), which is accessable from secret map 31: Wolfenstein. As you might have guessed by now, the levels/sprites are references to ID's other games. The level's name and other graphics are all Wolfenstein references though, the only Commander Keen reference is the killable prop.

You kill 4 Keens to open the exit of the level. He's just an object to hurt, he himself isn't an enemy and doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this sprite is a message from ID, specifically saying "Keen is dead".  You could say they weren't...Keen on releasing any more Keen games.

Comment: @Zibbobz more likely it is a message saying 'now we are a serious game company who does first person shooters, not platformer arcades anymore'